# Displaying totals without hitting performance in WPF & EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

[Figure 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FaWwS.jpg)

I have 4 Classes : Customer, Purchase, Product, Payment
which the relations as below :

1. Customer may have zero or many Purchases
2. Purchase may have one or many Products
3. Purchase may have 0 or many Payments

[Figure 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDgg6.jpg)

In the User interface i have to display a list of all customers with their : total amount of Purchases and total of payments and Total Debt or remaining payment.

**Problem :**

Loading all Customers with all their Purchases, Products and Payments just to display these totals will slow down displaying the data.

The solution i'm thinking about is to create these calculated Fields in the Client Database table but i have to update them whenever :
-I Add/Update/Delete : (Purchase/Payment/Product).

Using DB Views or Stored-procedures is not an option, i want to keep everything in the code.
What do you suggest to overcome this issue

PS : i'm using EntityFramework 6
Thanks in Advance

Comment: Have you tried `from c in customers select new { TotalPurchase = c.Purchases.Sum(p => p.Amount)}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it could "slow down" displaying the data, then it means that you've got a lot records to calculate. In the case if you're forced to calculate everything in application code, then you've got one option to make some sort of pagination.

By this you can avoid calculation of all records at once and you're able to calculate small chunks of whatever size you choose. 
One more option may be lazy loading, but it may impact eg. scrolling performance which i don't recommend.

Another option is to use LINQ projection that @AluanHaddad suggested to you. You can calculate your sum in the SQL query without using views / procedures.

IMO connection of the both (pagination & sum calculation in SQL query) is a correct way to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

@Ahmed HM
I think You should create two list. One with `List<Products>` and another one with `List<Payments>` to Purchase class and then in Customer Class you can create a Field where U can use LINQ to Obtain your totals doing something like this:

```
public decimal TotalPayments
{
    get
    {
       if (Purchase != null && Purchase.Payments != null && Purchase.Count > 0)
       {
          return Purchase.Select(k=>k.Payment.Sum(k=>k.Amount));
       }
    return 0.0M;
    }
}
```

Tell me If it was usefull to you. I'm not 100% secure you can use it as you want.